# Does SSD automatically move data off (few) bad sectors?

Tags: ssd, disk

Disks reports that my SSD "Disk is OK. 3 bad sectors".

Do SSDs automatically move data off of bad sectors, or should I assume I lost some files or data that were on those sectors?

[image: eScreenshot of Disks in Ubuntu 20.04.1]

Comment: 3 bad sectors is not a problem. Keep an eye on it. If it goes up very fast then the drive needs to be replaced.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for taking the time to offer me some advice, even thought question was marked off topic! I'll keep an eye on it. Hopefully it will remain stable until my new (backup) disk arrives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, the SSD firmware is smart enough to move the data off the bad sectors and avoid using those sectors in the future. The mere fact that the SMART data is reporting a non-zero bad sector count indicates the firmware is doing its job. As long as the number of bad sectors isn't increasing, you probably don't have too much too worry about - [Crucial states that a couple bad sectors isn't necessarily out of the ordinary.](https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/my-ssd-has-bad-sectors). That being said, backups are *never* a bad idea.

Comment: My SSD is actually a Crucial device, so appreciated the link you provided. Regarding backups, I 100% agree. In this case, my backup disk (a spinning disk) needs to be replaced, and I wanted to be sure this SSD was stable before I did anything with the other disk.